# MySQL online database

Tags: c#, mysql, web-services

I had learned how to use MySQL on local machine with C#, but what I can do if I want to use it online? I mean for example, I could connect XML and C# to share data online by putting the xml file on any server. What options are available for MySQL? Is there any way to do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have mentioned WCF, which is a great option, however MS has just released a beta but stable MVC 4. The MVC 4 update has a web API ability. This enables you to create web services quickly and easily.

Example Code using the Web API:

```
public class RecordsController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Record record)
    {
        var newId = _Records.Count + 1;
        record.ID = newId;
        _Records.Add(record);
        var newMessage = new HttpResponseMessage<Record>(record);
        return newMessage;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to setup a web service, take a look at [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) .

Take a look at [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/a-xml-web-service-that-exposes-the-default-table-from-sql-se/) example.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you would write a server back end which interacts with the database. This could be a `WCF Web Service` if you're using .Net, could be REST Web Services if using Java (.Net actually has REST as well), or a plethora of different things.

Your front end (browser application, etc.) would then interact with this server back end.